# How to setup scanning in Gradle?

Tags: jetty, gradle

Background:  I have a gradle project, and I use jettyRun with success.  I want Jetty to pick up code changes immediately without requiring a server bounce.  Gradle supports hot deploy, and I understand that all I need to do is turn on "scanning", but I am not sure exactly what I need to do.  Here's what I tried:

```
jettyRun {
    httpPort = 8989
    reload = 'automatic'
    scanIntervalSeconds = 2
    daemon = false 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it should work. Remember that the jetty plugin picks up the resources from the 'build' folder and not the from the src folder.

cheers,

René

Comment: Okay, so I have to manually run "gradle classes" on every change.  Was hoping there was an inherent way to setup a background thread to detect source changes and do this for me. _ Thanks.